# Boiling point of water in microwave oven

Tags: electric-fields

My textbook says that water heats so well in a microwave oven that people might be able to heat a cup of water as much as $8~C^{\circ}$ above the normal boiling temperature of water without causing it to boil.

Normally, the boiling point changes with atmosphere pressure, but I don't understand how putting water into a microwave oven raises the boiling point.

This fact is introduced in the introduction to electric fields, so I think it involves electric fields, but I am not exactly sure how.

Comment: Microwave heating does not raise the boiling point but it can heat from the inside to outside. Other cooking methods heat from the outside to inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microwave heating does not stir or shake the water. If the water is left quiet as it heats in the microwave, it is not hard to superheat it. At that point, the slightest disturbance will cause the water to explode into vapor all at once.

It is easy to superheat water like this if the heat deposition rate is high enough. Thermal inkjet printheads heat their ink (mostly water) at the rate of several hundred degrees C per microsecond and the ink typically hits 260C before the vaporization process is nucleated on the surface of the heater resistors.

Comment: When I heat water in a kettle or a pot it is also left undisturbed by mechanical work. "Turbulence" first occurs once the water starts boiling. Does water heated in a microwave not start boiling at some point? And if so, how isn't the "violent" motion of the boiling water not enough to prevent superheating?

Comment: @playdis, pots heated on a stove heat from the bottom, and so convective motion is present in the water, which always starts boiling from the bottom first. a jar of water heated in a microwave heats evenly throughout and so convective motion is not present.